# one word for a sentiment close to ignorant or illiterate

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

I want a word to describe people who despite of their education and economic status and apparent sophistication, are lacking of even the most basic level of critical thinking. People who will just readily accept whatever is the norm.

EDIT: I am looking for a noun. adjective suggestions are also welcome

Comment: Sounds like a bit of a peeve.

Answer (score 2):

Although you yourself named the most suitable word- *Ignorance*.

But there are some other expressions for the above description-

> - An educated fool.
> - A literate fool.

I used the above expressions as you described that someone to have a low level of thinking despite of their education level.

Examples utilizing the above expressions-

> Despite of all his degrees & certificates, he's literally an educated fool when it comes to *financial* matters.

Answer (score 2):

A suitable word might be 'unquestioning' if the focus was upon a lack of critical thinking. You might also use 'conformist' for someone who accepts prevailing opinion without question or concern.

Answer (score 1):

> People who will just readily accept whatever is the norm.

*Sheep* is a common word for *followers*.

> [sheep](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+sheep&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=sb): a person who is too easily influenced or led.

[stooge, yes-man, flunky](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/follower) - a person of unquestioning obedience.

> CHRIS HUGHTON insists he is not a *yes-man* for Mike Ashley's regime and will fight to strengthen Newcastle's squad in January.

[mindless](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mindless): showing, using, or requiring no intelligence or thought.

[marionette](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/marionette): a *puppet* (manipulated from above by strings attached to its jointed limbs.) (*Blockhead* would suffice as well.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you may be looking for is 'blinkered'. Another metaphor is of someone unable to think 'outside the box'. But I am not sure how to form a noun or adjective from it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that [uncritical](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/A+critical) may come close to your definition:

- not inclined or able to judge or evaluate: an uncritical reader.

This is an interesting issue. Some people, despite their education and economic wealth, seem to lack critical judgement with respect a number of issues. I think that it comes down more to a question of personal character and attitude rather than education.

Comment: offtopic but IMO all people are capable of critical thinking but unfortunately our education system is so hopelessly shallow that many people just end up being uncritical.

Answer (score 1):

Nouns:

*Ignoramus, know-nothing.*

You can also mix and match contrasting adjectives and nouns to your heart's content to match the specific context, e.g. *clever idiot, unworldly genius, witless expert, professorial nincompoop, clueless prodigy, intellectual helot.*